# Instalação do Unity está dando erro

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, packages

Fui instalar o Unity para DI e pelo NuGet está dando um erro, que não entendi, parece-me que ele aponta para o NewtonSoft, veja o erro abaixo:

> Install-Package : An error occurred while retrieving package metadata
>   for 'Newtonsoft.Json.10.0.2' from source 
>   'C:\Sites\meu_projeto_webapi\packages'. At line:1 char:1
>   + Install-Package Unity
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

Tentei remover assim:
`PM> Unistall-Package Newtonsoft.Json RemoveDependencies` e dá um erro semelhante ao de cima, mas com essa mensagem:

> 'RemoveDependencies' is not found.

Answer (score 1):

Recentemente tive o mesmo problema com o Newtonsoft. Consegui resolver atualizando.

```
Update-Package Newtonsoft.Json
```

Comment: Já fiz isso e continuo não conseguindo instalar o Unity. Vou remover o NewtonSoft e tentar instalar o outro pacote e por último o Newtonsoft.Json.

Comment: Pós você ter atualizado o pacote, ele te retornou o mesmo erro?

Comment: Pelo NuGet não consigo remover. Fiz isso: `Uninstall-Package Newtonsoft.Json` e dá erro. Há outra forma de eu desinstalar?

Comment: Na atualização não, ele atualizou, pelo menos não deu erro algum.

Comment: Ele tem algumas dependências, você tem que desinstala-las.

Comment: Sim, fiz isso: `Uninstall-Package Newtonsoft.Json RemoveDependencies`, a menos que a linha acima esteja errada, não funcionou também

Comment: Veja se essa solução resolve o seu problema.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32794295/4312593

Answer (score 0):

Este erro não é relacionado ao Unity, exatamente. Por algum motivo, seu Visual Studio não conseguiu se conectar ao NuGet.

Experimente executar o seguinte comando antes de tentar instalar o Unity novamente, no Package Manager Console:

```
PM> Update-Package
```

---

Não acho uma boa ideia remover o JSON.NET, mas, de qualquer forma, o comando correto é:

```
PM> Unistall-Package Newtonsoft.Json -RemoveDependencies
```

Comment: Então, já fiz isso com e sem hífen e dá o erro que coloquei no post original(Editei). Com o -force me dá esse erro: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`. Vou atualizar e tentar reinstalar o Unity.

Comment: Nem consigo desinstalar e nem instalar o Unity, agora tô na roça mesmo.

Comment: Sim, mas não remova o JSON.NET. Ele é usado em todas as operações. Eu só adicionei essa parte na resposta para questão de conhecimento.

Comment: Eu sei, a intenção seria desinstalar, instalar os dois outro pacotes e depois por último instalar o Newton. Essa é a idéia, pois preciso dele para comunicação Json e etc...

Comment: Aproveitando, por que não usa o [SimpleInjector](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SimpleInjector/) ao invés do Unity?

Comment: Posso tentar, é que no exemplo o autor instalou esse pacote, mas posso substituir sim, seria um plus no curso.

Comment: Cigano, deu o mesmo erro que o Unity, ou seja, fazendo referência ao Newton.

Comment: Então não é erro do Unity ou do Simple Injector. É erro do NuGet. É possível iniciar um projeto novo?

Comment: Reiniciei o VS2015 e vou testar agora, senão inicio outro projeto pra testes e tento instalar tudo novamente.

Comment: Criei um projeto de testes WebApi, vi que a Newtonsoft.Json já estava instalada e consegui instalar a Unity nesse novo, porém no anterior, reiniciei o VS2015 e mesmo assim, não consegui instalar. Dá o mesmo erro.